# 500: Internal server error on Laravel 5.2 project

Tags: laravel, upload, laravel-5

I want to upload a Laravel 5.2 project on live server.when I upload it and try to run then give me 500: Internal-Server Error.

How Can I Fix This?

Comment: How should we know? Provide at least some more information like error messages..

Comment: i Keep  all project file in the public_html folder and separate public folder also .but when i  try to run then give  error

Comment: Have you tried checking the logs at /app/storage/logs?

Comment: i change the index.php file look like this ....

Comment: require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

Comment: $app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';

Comment: no i not check logs

Comment: how can i check log

Comment: as I explained above navigate to /app/storage/logs in the laravel directory and cat the latest .log file in there. If it is a laravel error, it shoule be listed there

Comment: yes i check  log file  and it first  throw exception is

Comment: [2017-02-21 09:26:16] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Use of undefined constant apple - assumed 'apple'' in /home/hannan/nabanno/storage/framework/views/4ea3848f1f53913cf994a287faa80d992683dedd.php:10

Comment: how can i fix this

Comment: `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: Show us the code around that line in that file. It looks like you've done something like `echo apple` instead of `echo 'apple'`.

Answer (score -1):

In the most cases, this error happens because of folders and files permissions (in the case of laravel, may be the .env missing)

To fix this, check if you have the .env file in your folder

If not:

Generate your .env:

```
cp .env.example .env
```

Generate your key:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

After that, give the correct permissions to your laravel folder.

Enter in the laravel project

```
cd my_project_folder
```

Add the 644 permission to files and 755 to folders:

```
find ./ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find ./ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Clear your cache

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

If another error appears, try to update your composer

```
composer update
```

Comment: There are many, many causes for an error 500 this wouldn't solve. Missing required PHP extensions, different versions of PHP, different error reporting settings, etc. Better to first look at the logs before going around chmodding everything randomly.

Comment: I'm not setting randomly permissions, a lot of answer in stackoverflow recommend that, [here for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others)

Comment: Given OP's comment that the logs show `local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Use of undefined constant apple - assumed 'apple''` this has **nothing** to do with permissions, and as such, changing permissions **is** pointless random flailing.

Answer (score -1):

First Check if the domain is redirecting to your public folder.

If yes , check the .env file and the database is conected .
Clear all the cache manually :

Bootstrap : services.php, settings.php Delete

Storage/Framework/Cache Delete all files

Storage/Framework/session Delete all files

Storage/Framework/views Delete all files

or if you have ssh access :

```
php artisan cache:clear php artisan config:clear php artisan view:clear
```

If still not working . check if the permmisons for storage folder are correct.
good luck :)

Comment: A 500 error is almost always caused by an issue with the code and generates a useful error in a log file. This is fairly pointless flailing around in the dark for the described problem.